# Username and password of Jenkins on Openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I've installed Jenkins via Openshift redhat (https://openshift.redhat.com) .. The installation of Jenkins is done..

[image]

To access to the interface of Jenkins I've used the username and password of my Openshift account and unfortunately it doesn't work ...

This is the error :

[image]

I want to mention that the setup of rhc is done in my local also.
Any idea ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer

To resume : I should login via ssh to my Jenkins application :

```
ssh 56b969d****@jenkins-***.rhcloud.com
```

You will find the exact ssh command for your app on the openshift page for the jenkins application under `Remote Access` hidden behind a hyperlink that says `Want to log in to your application?`

After that I do :

```
cat jenkins/env/JENKINS_USERNAME

cat jenkins/env/JENKINS_PASSWORD
```

And I ve got my login :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

ssh into your application and use the `env | grep JENKINS` command to view your username/password for jenkins: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#jenkins-variables

Comment: Thank you .. however this is the information I've got after executing : env | grep jenkins:

OPENSHIFT_JENKINS_DIR= *****
OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME= *****
OPENSHIFT_JENKINS_IDENT= *****
OPENSHIFT_JENKINS_CLIENT_IDENT= *****
OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS= *****
OPENSHIFT_PRIMARY_CARTRIDGE_DIR= *****
OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS= *****
PS1= *****
JENKINS_URL= *****
OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME= *****
OPENSHIFT_JENKINS_CLIENT_DIR= *****

Comment: did you ssh into your jenkins gear or your application gear?

Comment: I m not sure ... I think in the Jenkins gear .. : this is a screenshot from where i ve got the ssh connection: http://snag.gy/trB7K.jpg

Comment: You want to ssh into an application that is using the jenkins gear, not the jenkins gear itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I dont understand .. I want to have the login access for Jenkins it self! not an application using Jenkins ... I'm missing something I'm sure :(

Comment: AH! I found the answer :) .. it is in the same ssh I've used and after that I use : cat jenkins/env/JENKINS_USERNAME (system_builder) and cat jenkins/env/JENKINS_PASSWORD ... You have inspired me .... thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yep click below link(want to log in to your application) on your applications page, you will see a ssh string for you to login

[image]

Then

```
  cat jenkins/env/JENKINS_USERNAME 
  cat jenkins/env/JENKINS_PASSWORD
```

you will see your username and password